# Preposition about the Entries of the Product of Markov Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, markov-process, stochastic-matrices

***Definition***: A Markov matrix is an $n \times n$ complex matrix with the sum of the elements in every column equal to 1.

My task is to prove that:
If A, B are Markov matrices such that $|a_{ij}|\leq1$ and $|b_{ij}|\leq1$ for all i, j and if $A B = C = (c_{ij})$, then $|c_{ij}|\leq1$ for all i, j.

***Note***: In this case $|z|$ denotes the standard complex norm $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, where $z=a+bi$.

One potentially useful fact that I am aware of is that if $A, B$ are Markov matrices, then so is $AB$.

Comment: The entries in a stochastic matrix represent transition probabilities, so why would you consider complex values?

Comment: It's just the definition that my textbook gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
\newcommand{\conj}[1]{\overline{#1}}$$

It turns out that the preposition is just plain false. The author made a mistake.

Consider the complex number: $\omega = \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

By the author's definition of $\abs{z}$, 
$$ \abs{\omega} = \abs{\conj{\omega}}= \sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)^2+\Bigl(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Bigr)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}} = 1 $$

Now, let:

$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\conj{\omega}\\
\conj{\omega}&\omega
\end{bmatrix}\;and\; N = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\conj{\omega}&\omega\\
\omega&\conj{\omega}
\end{bmatrix}
$

M and N are both Markov matrix by the author's definition, since  $\omega + \conj{\omega} = 1$. It is furthermore true $\abs{a_{ij}} \leq 1$ for all entries of both M and N.

But $ M \times N =
\begin{bmatrix}
\omega&\conj{\omega}\\
\conj{\omega}&\omega
\end{bmatrix}  
 \times
\begin{bmatrix}
\conj{\omega}&\omega\\
\omega&\conj{\omega}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2\omega\conj{\omega}&*\\
*&*
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \times 1&*\\
*&*
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
2&*\\
*&*
\end{bmatrix}
$.
Therefore the product does not satisfy the condition that all entries have absolute value less than or equal to one, and thus the preposition is false.